# Replace nodejs for python?

Tags: python, node.js, webserver

i'm working in a HTML5 multiplayer game, and i need a server to sync player's movement, chat, battles, etc. So I'm looking for ways to use python instead nodejs, because i have  I have more familiarity with python. The server is simple:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

var onlines = 0
var users = []
var chat = ''

io.on('connection', function(socket){  
  console.log('[!] Um jogador conectou-se.');
  onlines += 1
  io.emit('updateonlines', [onlines]);
  socket.emit('recvmessage', [chat]);

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('[!] Um jogador desconectou-se.');
    onlines -= 1
    io.emit('updateonlines', [onlines]);
  });
});
  [...]
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Please note that a "simple" app in NodeJS *does not* translate in to a simple Python app. As far as I know Nodes claim to fame is being a simple way to write `event-driven, non-blocking I/O` apps. So it sounds like you what you want is Node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/). It is well-documented and features built-in support for `WebSockets`.

If you want to steer clear of the `Tornado`-framework, there are several Python implementations of `Socket.io`.

Good luck!